# Regex extract Json attributes name

Tags: regex, text, screen-scraping, text-extraction

I am looking to extract all the attributes name of a Json string. I came out with an expression but it doesn't work for some specific scenario,
The expression I build is the following

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)"(?::\s(?:"[a-zA-Z0-9-\s:]*")|(?:\s^null$)|(?:\s[0-9]+,))
```

And it works fine for attribute like these :

```
{"dataAreaId": "cel",    "CustomerAccount": "C101112",    "AddressBrazilianCNPJOrCPF": "",    "PartyType": "Organization"}
```

But it doest retrieve/match the attribute for these :

```
{ "DeliveryAddressLongitude": 0,"AddressTimeZone": null,"FullPrimaryAddress": "7800 Avenue Aurtweuil Suite 28841\nBrossard QC J2Z 3P1\nCanada"}
```

I will really appreciate having any guideline about it as I am struggling.

Cheers

VIncent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generated json you'd only have to match the word preceding a colon, right, while accounting for quotes? For example:

```
/("?)(\b\w+\b)\1:/gm
```

Edit:

- `/.../gm`: `g` and `m` are flags that modify the behaviour of the expression, where g (global) means *try to find all matches in the string* and m (multiline) means *make every line in the string anchorable by `^` and `$`*; you actually don't need the `m` flag here, that was an oversight on my part. 
  Depending on regex flavour you'll use flags as seen above - after the second expression delimiter, as parameters for match functions or as in-expression modifiers like `(?g)`. I just find `/.../flags` a good shortcut to show an expression with flags.
- `\b` is a word boundary that anchors a sequence of word characters by making sure there can't be a word character on both sides of it; if there is, the expression won't match. In this expression I just use it to make the engine fail bad strings a little bit quicker while accounting for the optional `"`. They aren't strictly needed for this expression when you use it only on well-formed JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Work like a charm.Could you explain why you use workd boundaries \ and why the /gm ? Regards

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort Thanks for asking. I edited my answer. If I'm not being clear, please ask again. Cheers.